# How to return value from subscription?

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

I have a function, which makes query and processes it rezult in the subscription. This function must return 200 if query was successful or error codes in other cases. What I need to do to return value I got in the subscription?

```ts
public loginEmail(email: string, password: string): Subscription {
    return this.http.post < any > (`http://127.0.0.1:8080/user/`, {}, {
            params: new HttpParams().set('email', email).set('password', password)
        })
        .subscribe(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
            this.user.setUser(resp['user'])
            return 200;
        }, error => {
            return error.code
        });
}
```

Comment: I want to understand the use case that you had to rely on 200, rather than that, if you have something in your html template like *ngIf, which will render some conditional html component on the basis of response, you can place the condition on the user property of the component.......... <label *ngIf="user">This will be displayed only when 'user' have some valid value</label>

Comment: This piece of code located in the service and returns value to the component.

Comment: return the user object as an observable, and subcribe to that observable in your component, why returning the status code of the http response then?

Comment: Can't you just return new observable from the method?

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47507179/681929) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55442329/681929) , I think if you will search this on google, 'how to return data from http request from a service to a component', you will get tons of results